# Stuck at Extended Euclidean Algorithm to solve equation

Tags: euclidean-geometry, inverse

I'm trying to solve the following function via the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, but I'm stuck at the last step where I need to sub in sub 2.

```
d * 7 = 1 (mod 180)
d = 1 / 7 (mod 180)
d = 7-1 (mod 180)
180 = 7 * 25 + 5
7 = 5 * 1 + 2
5 = 2 * 2 + 1
1 = 5 – 2 * 2
sub 2 = 7 – 5
1 = 5 – (7 – 5) * 2
```

How should I simplify this now? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Group the $5$ terms and $7$ terms on the right hand side; substitute $5 = 180 - 7\times 25$

Comment: @peterwhy When I do this I get: 1 = 5 – 2 * (7 – 5), sub 5 = 180 – 7 * 25, so it will become 1 = 5 – 2 * (7 – 180 – 7 * 25). Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Euclidean algorithm (first part):

$$\begin{align*}
180 =& 7\times25 + 5\\
7 =& 5\times1 + 2\\
5 =& 2\times2 + 1
\end{align*}$$

Then the second part of Extended Euclidean algorithm:

$$\begin{align*}
1 =& 5 - 2\times2\\
=& 5 - (7-5\times1)\times2 &&\text{Substitute }2 = 7 - 5\times1\\
=& 7\times(-2) + 5 \times3 &&\text{Group }7\text{ and }5\text{ terms}\\
=& 7\times(-2) + (180-7\times25) \times3 &&\text{Substitute }5 = 180 - 7\times25\\
=& 180\times3 - 7\times77 &&\text{Group }180\text{ and }7\text{ terms}
\end{align*}$$

Now, you should use this result to obtain $7^{-1} \pmod{180}$.